# Sharing images using facebook sdk integration

Tags: android, facebook

In my app I am trying to integrate facebook sharing.I want to share image with this.I am using publish_action permission.I have created app on facebook developer site.And when I am adding item for submission it shows me dialogue as it is in the picture.
[image]

as the text rounded with red rectangular box it says test permission with ROles then I added a member for testing purposes.In the begining it was showing (pending) in bracket with my test user then it went away.I have searched and read that I need to submit for using "publish_action", but when I am submitting this app it take me to the top and shows red alter box which says "you need to test with test user" as in the picture below 
[image]
for this I logged in device with that tester user which I registered but it is still showing this error.My question is why is this error for?Am I missing something?

I tried with test account and run the app it showed me as is in the picture

[image]

I completed the procedure by clicking ok and it completed everything but when I checked facebook it did not post or share any thing and when I tried to post again nothing is happening Fist time it took me to the procedure as in the picture but after this nothing is being shown.

This is the code I am using

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(mActivity, permissionNeeds);
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            sharePhotoToFacebook();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
```

Program execution not hitting any of the callback method and below is the method that is to call on onSuccess() callback.

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Testing text")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    ShareApi.share(content, null);

}
```

Comment: You need to run your application once with test account and share something, there should be atleast one api call for sharing from test account.

Comment: I ran and shared and I have updated what happened next.

Comment: Is this still an issue? try posting as a admin through the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)